# Strange console errors persisting after "git reset --hard"

Tags: console, gsap, react-dom

I'm working in React on VSCode and installed Moment.js via npm. For reasons I'm sure are unrelated all of a sudden I started receiving console errors to the tune of this: [console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGZ7x.png). After trying to solve the errors by working through some potentially troubling GSAP syntax, they all still remained. I used git reset --hard to get me back to a point at which I knew the app was fully functional but the errors have persisted. I don't know what could have happened! Here's the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/connorwhite-online/connorwhite.online/feature/contact?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.css&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl8ghm8je000ilnfw944b4nn6%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl8ghmaff00os3b6rv44sderm%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl8ghmugs00ze3b6rhk9zr12k%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl8ghmr6i00xd3b6ruump8iuq%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D), let me know if you spot anything funky!

Thanks,
Connor